# Plotting w/ Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, graph, google-colaboratory

I am working in Google Colab, and am wondering why I am getting a bad graph when trying to plot my data with Matplotlib.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('TSLA.csv')

df_raw = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_working = df_raw[['Date', 'Adj Close']]

df_adj_close = df_working['Adj Close'].rolling(window = 50).mean()
rolling_50 = df_adj_close.rolling(window = 50).mean()
rolling_200 = df_adj_close.rolling(window = 200).mean()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
x = df_working['Date']
y = df_working['Adj Close']
a = rolling_50
b = rolling_200
plt.plot(x, y, a, b)
plt.xlabel("X-axis")
plt.ylabel("Y-axis")
plt.title('Title')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
plt.plot(x, y, a, b)
```

With:

```
plt.plot(x, y, x, a, x, b)
```

*Edit: Explanation:*

Assuming that the plot needs:

x_axis --> x (common to all three plots)

y_axis --> y, a, and b

In the above code `plt.plot(x, y, a, b)` does not have a common x-axis. And it code is plotting  x vs y and a vs. b on the same plot, with 'different' x_axis values. Therefore, `plt.plot(x, y, x, a, x, b)` now would create an overlay of three plots with the same common x_axis.

Comment: Please add an explanation as to why this change would make it work.

Comment: @Alex Stephens: Added explanation as requested.